# リストの要素をランダムに組み合わせて表示する

Tags: python

2つのリストから要素をランダムに組み合わせて表示していく方法についてです。

２つのリストlistAとlistBがあり、それぞれに100個の要素があります。
各リストから一つずつ要素をランダムで取り出し、ペアで数字を全て表示していきます。その際、表示する位置もランダムにしたいと考えています。
表示した際、
【A1　B3】
【B70  A50】
【A23  B40】
…
となるようにです。

listAとBからランダムに要素を取り出し、それらをさらにランダムに別の２つのリストlistC、listDに格納していき、最終的にlistCとDの要素をペアで表示できればと考えています。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

新たな条件追加がありましたので下記のように変更しました。

```
import random
x = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6']
y = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6']
random.shuffle(x)
random.shuffle(y)
shuffled = [[i, j] for i, j in zip(x, y)]

ar1 = [shuffled[j - 1] for j in random.sample([i + 1 for i in range(len(shuffled))], int(len(shuffled) / 2))]
ar2 = [[i[1], i[0]] for i in tuple(set(map(tuple, ar1)) ^ set(map(tuple, shuffled)))]
ar1.extend(ar2)
result = [ar1[i] for i in random.sample(range(len(ar1)), len(ar1))]

listC = [z[0] for z in result]
listD = [z[1] for z in result]
print(listC)
print(listD)

>>> ['a3', 'b5', 'a5', 'b2', 'b4', 'a6']
>>> ['b1', 'a1', 'b6', 'a2', 'a4', 'b3']
```

流れは次の通りです。

1. a群, b群をそれぞれシャッフルして2次元配列を作成
2. ar1 → 2次元配列からその要素数の半分をランダムで取得
3. ar2 → 残りの半分に対してそれぞれの要素を入れ替え
4. result → それぞれを足し合わせて順番をシャッフル
5. listC, listD → 分離

Comment: 一つのリストにしてシャッフルした後、 (a1, a2) のように、同じ要素のペアができてしまうことはないでしょうか。

Comment: シャッフルしたa群, b群それぞれのリストを１つの2次元リストにし、そのそれぞれの要素についてシャッフルを行っていますので、a, aやb, bになることはありません。a, bあるいはb, aのペアが出力されますのでご安心ください。

Comment: なるほど。　質問後半部分にある、「listAとBからランダムに要素を取り出し、それらをさらにランダムに別の２つのリストlistC、listDに格納していき、最終的にlistCとDの要素をペアで表示できればと考えています」ですが、この場合、一つにしたリストを再度別の二つのリスト (listCとlistD) に、要素ごとに格納するにはどうするのがスマートでしょうか。listCには['a5', 'b3', 'a3', 'b1', 'b4']、listDには['b3', 'a2', 'b5', 'a1', 'a4']のようにです。

Comment: 回答へ追記しましたのでご確認ください。

Comment: 始めにshuffuledのリストを作る際、iとjにaとbが半分ずつ入っているのでしょうか。もし違う場合、半分ずつ格納できればと考えています。

Comment: 本件、解決していなかったようで申し訳ありません。"半分ずつ"の意味が分かりませんが、動作としてはa群、b群の1次元リストをそれぞれでシャッフルした後に2次元のリストにまとめています。その2次元リストのそれぞれの要素について0番目と1番目の2つでさらにシャッフルしています。値を確認したい場所でprint文を使用するとより分かりやすいかと思います。printの使い方はこちらです。 http://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: こちらこそ説明不足でした。半分ずつというのは、2次元配列の0番目 (回答でいうところの、'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'a4', 'a5') と1番目の要素 ('b4', 'a2', 'a1', 'b5', 'b3') に、list xの要素が半分ずつ、同様にlist yも、ということです。

Comment: 返事が遅くなり申し訳ありません。スクリプトを変更しましたのでご確認ください。新たに追加された条件である"半分ずつ"を組み込みました。

Answer (score 1):

`zip`がタプルを返すので、 それに合わせてイミュータブルを扱うコードです。
シャッフルの手順はTanaikeさんと同じです。

```
import random

def imshuffle(x):
    return random.sample(x,k=len(x))

listA=[1,2,3,4,5]
listB=[6,7,8,9,10]

shuffled=map(imshuffle, zip(imshuffle(listA),imshuffle(listB)))

[listC,listD]=map(list,zip(*shuffled))

print shuffled
print listC
print listD
```

`random.sample(x,k=len(x))`は[公式のドキュメントから](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/random.html#random.shuffle)借りてきたイミュータブルなシャッフルです。

実行結果

```
% python shuffle.py
[[2, 7], [6, 5], [1, 9], [8, 3], [10, 4]]
[2, 6, 1, 8, 10]
[7, 5, 9, 3, 4]
```